# Cart software similar to WordPress in ability to customize

Tags: wordpress, loops, cart

I'm looking for a Cart software that can be customized and stripped down like a WordPress theme can be.

What I mean is that I'd like to run something similar to "Loops" in WP for my products being sold.

So for example I can set the WP template to Loop only items from Featured category, maxing out at 5 products, and only listing the Product's Title and Price. I can have an entire page where that's the only content that is dynamic. There would be a separate template for the "single-item" view.

So ideally I would create the product through an Admin panel and have mostly static content. The Cart system would allow me to loop products of a particular type where I want them and only the variables I want shown. Just like WP blog posts.

In addition, I do need to have "Coupon Codes" functioning as well.

I hope this is making sense, if not please let me know.

---

I initially thought that something build on Angular JS could work or maybe even simpleCart(js) but I thought I'd ask for some suggestions as I believe both of these have their own issues.

Although an Angular build cart does sound nice for what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the basis of WooCommerce you can exactly do that. The template system of WooCommerce is much like WordPress. You can simply loop trough your products and call simular functions to display data. A product in WooCommerce is exactly the same as a post in WordPress, except it has a different "post_type" and additional post_meta.